# What is difference between .fun: and fun: in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, gnu-assembler

```
.section .data
msg1:
    .asciz "Hello1: %d\r\n"
msg2:
    .asciz "Hello2: %d\r\n"

.section .text
.global main

main:
    mov r4, #0         
.loop:
    cmp r4, #5          
    bge .endloop         
    ldr r0, =msg1       
    mov r1, r4
    bl printf          
    add r4, r4, #1      
    b .loop            
.endloop:
    mov r7, #1          
    mov r0, #0         
    swi 0
```

My assembly code runs on Raspberry Pi 4B, why is it that when I replace `.loop:` with `loop:` and `.endloop:` with `endloop:`, it still executes normally? What are the differences between `.loop:` and `loop:`? Thank you.

Comment: They are different symbols.  Ie, '.fun' and 'fun' are as different as 'fun' and 'endloop'.  They symbols are special to coders.  They let us put meaning to code sections.  This is why the local labels that Peter refers to are good.  The labels 'loop' and 'endloop' are not really helpful notes.  Too many labels can obscure the good information.  In a big file you would have 'loop1', ''loop2', 'loop3', etc. and then you may  copy/paste and jump to the wrong place.  It is better to use local labels for patterns like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference, they're just label names.  `.` is a valid character in asm symbols, including as the first character.

But by convention, `.` labels are "local" to the function.  In NASM syntax (an x86 assembler), they are actually scoped that way, so you can have `.loop` inside multiple different functions.

In GNU Assembler (GAS) like here, `.loop` isn't special at all; it would be an error (symbol redefinition) to have `foo:` ; `.loop:` earlier or later in the file.

`.Lxyz` labels that start with a dot and capital L are special (not appearing in the symbol table of the `.o` at all even for debugging), but still file-scoped. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html  This is why GCC uses label names like `.L0` for branch targets within functions (if/else/loops/etc) and names like `.LC0` for constants in `.rodata`, and even stuff like `.Lanchor0` for locations it wants to mark to reference other stuff relative to.

For actual local labels in GAS that you can define more than once, use bare numbers like `1:` and refer to it with `1b` for backwards to the nearest `1` in that direction, `1f` for the nearest `1:` in the forward direction.  Like `1: bhi 1b` is an infinite loop or not depending on the carry and zero flags.